# How to find all possible consecutive triplets in a string?

Tags: python, string, tuples, bioinformatics, triplet

My question is that if you have a string of DNA, how could you create a list of all possible consecutive triplets? For instance, if you have the following string:

ACCTAA

I need to create a list of all possible consecutive triplets, such that:

ACC, CCT, CTA, TAA

How could I accomplish that?

So far, I have only figured out how to create a list of triplets by dividing the string at equal intervals:

```
list_of_triplet = [dna[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(dna), 3)]
```

Where `dna` is the input string.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Your approach is fine. Change the `list()` to `set()` for unique triplets.

Comment: Thank you for the help! However, I do not use the `list()` function in my code. Could you please clarify where I should change the code? Have I missed something?

Comment: `list()` is type of object in python, you can also use `[]` to do them. I was a bit unclear but both answers here show both ways of creating different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Let's remove the third parameter in the `range` function (you don't really want to split the string in groups of three). Also, we want to stop when there are only 3 characters left, so the second parameter should be `len(dna) - 2`. With all this, you have:

```py
list_of_triplet = [dna[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(dna) - 2)]
```

If you don't want the triplets to be repeated, you can instead use a set comprehension:

```py
list_of_triplet = {dna[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(dna) - 2)}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It works perfectly! I did not consider that it needs to stop when there are less than 3 strings left, however it is logical. Thanks again for the assist. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have multitude of options

With iterator

```py
unique_triplets = set(dna[i:i+3] for i in range(len(dna) - 2)
print(unique_triplets)
# {'ACC', 'TAA', 'CTA', 'CCT'}
```

With iterating

```py
unique_triplets = set()
for i in range(len(dna) - 2):
    unique_triplets.add(dna[i:i+3])
print(unique_triplets)
# {'ACC', 'TAA', 'CTA', 'CCT'}
```

If you want counts of the values use `defaultdict`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
unique_triplets = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(len(dna) - 2):
    unique_triplets[dna[i:i+3]] += 1

print(unique_triplets)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'ACC': 1, 'CCT': 1, 'CTA': 1, 'TAA': 1})
```